# Firebase How to update multiple children?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have parent with many children like this:

```
 Parent:{
        "childe1":"data",
        "childe2":"data",
        "childe3":"data",
        "childe4":"data",
        "childe5":"data"
 }
```

How can I update the children `[ childe1 , childe2 , childe3 ]` at same time, preventing any other user from updating them at same time?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To update multiple properties at the same time, you can run an `update()` call:

```
ref.child("Parent").update({
  childe1: "newdata",
  childe2: "newdata",
  childe3: "newdata"
});
```

You can even specify paths as the keys, in case the properties are at different levels in the tree. Even though that doesn't seem to be the case here, the syntax would be:

```
ref.update({
  "Parent/childe1": "newdata",
  "Parent/childe2": "newdata",
  "Parent/childe3": "newdata"
});
```

The exact validation depends a bit on what you'd like to allow, but in general you'd [write `.validate` rules on the server that validate that `newData` meet your requirements](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data).

Comment: Is it possible to do something like "Parent/*" to update all children in a single call?

Comment: Nope. To update a value, you need to know its complete path.

Comment: Thank you so much ... Before seeing this,...i am making 2 request for just parent field update & child's nested key update....