# Adding multiple children to Firebase database with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create multiple children inside a child. I can currently create this inside my recipe:

```
{
  "RecipeData": {
    "recipe": {
      "-KjTSH4uPQ152Cr-hDok": {
        "name": "Cook rice",
        "ID": "-KjTSH4uPQ152Cr-hDok",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using:

```
let recipe: [String : Any] = ["name" : self.recipe.name,
                              "ID" : self.recipe.key]
```

The class of the recipe looks like this:

```
class Recipe {

    var name: String!
    var key: String

    init(from snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

        self.name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
        self.key = snapshot.key  
    }
}
```

But I now want to create another array of children which would be inside "method" and look something like this.

```
{
  "RecipeData": {
    "recipe": {
      "-KjTSH4uPQ152Cr-hDok": {
        "name": "Cook rice",
        "ID": "-KjTSH4uPQ152Cr-hDok",
        "method": [
          {
            "step 1": "instruction 1"
          },
          {
            "step 2": "instruction 2"
          },
          {
            "step 3": "instruction 3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

The recipe is updated this way

```
databaseRef.child("RecipeData").child("recipe").updateChildValues(recipe)
```

I have looked at [Firebase How to update multiple children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878551/firebase-how-to-update-multiple-children) which is written in javascript, but not sure how to implement it. Feel free to let me know if there are better questions or examples out there.

Comment: Show use the full structure inside which parent you have added this name and id

Comment: @NiravD Please see my updated structure

Comment: Are you having that recipe Id where you want to add this array?

Comment: No, the recipe ID is already being added to the recipe.

Comment: What I'm saying is how do you know in which recipe you need to add this methods now by updating it or there is only one recipe ?

Comment: Yes, sorry please see my edit which shows how I update the recipe.

Comment: @NiravD I've updated my structure again to show the full structure

Comment: What I'm saying is to change specific child recipe you need its id are you having that or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create multiple children inside of a node just as you have been doing with the `"recipe"` node. For example:

```
{
  "RecipeData": {
    "recipe": {
      "-KjTSH4uPQ152Cr-hDok": {
        "name": "Cook rice",
        "ID": "-KjTSH4uPQ152Cr-hDok",
        "method": {
          "Step1":"instruction1",
          "Step2":"instruction2",
          "Step3":"instruction3"

        }
     }
   }
 }
```

This is better practice as you can look up each step by key. Although, as Firebase Database keys are **strings ordered lexicographically**, it would be better practice to use `.childByAutoId()` for each step, to ensure all the steps come in order and are unique. I'll just keep using "step*n*" for this example though.

If you needed further information inside each step, just make one of the step keys a parent node again:

```
{
  "RecipeData": {
    "recipe": {
      "-KjTSH4uPQ152Cr-hDok": {
        "name": "Cook rice",
        "ID": "-KjTSH4uPQ152Cr-hDok",
        "method": {
          "Step1": {
             "SpatulaRequired" : true,
             "Temp" : 400
          }

        }
     }
   }
 }
```

This can be achieved by by calling `.set()` on a Dictionary of Dictionaries. For example:

```
let dict: [String:AnyObject] = ["Method":
                                ["Step1":
                                 ["SpatulaRequired":true,
                                             "temp":400],
                                ["Ste‌​p2":
                                 ["SpatulaRequire‌​d":false,
                                             "temp":500]‌​
                                ]]

myDatabaseReference.set(dict)
```

Comment: Thanks Bradley, this makes much more sense as you mention it'll allow me to refer to it using the key in the future. But how would I add all of this at once? I am trying to do all of this within one action.

Comment: You can call `.set()` on a Dictionary of Dictionaries and it'll just work. For example: `["Method":["Step1":["SpatulaRequired":true,"temp":400],["Step2":["SpatulaRequired":false,"temp":500]]]`

Comment: @BradleyMackey Good answer and a couple of things. Please add the code in your comment to your answer as it will be easier to read - also make sure it's Swift to match the tag in the OP. Also, naming the nodes within *method* as you suggest may be an issue as step1 will be followed by step10, not step2. You may want to use childByAutoId to generate the parent keys for those nodes as that will order them correctly (or use a numeric integer index as a child (step: 1, step: 2, step: 3) etc).You may want to denormalize this structure as well as it's a little deep.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It is much clearer, I have been able to create my database in the same structure you have provided where the method gets its own unique ID. However how do I refer to the methods ID. At the moment I can only refer to the recipe ID. Sorry if this is off topic.

Comment: Assuming your methods ID is the `"ID"` field, it seems somewhat redundant to me, are you sure you need it if there's only 1 method per recipe?

Comment: Yes that's true, so if I created an autoID for each `"step"`. Then how would I refer to each step ID?

Comment: I'm thinking the `"step"` will have to be a separate class that has it's own key. Would that be the correct way to do it?

Comment: @Chace that would probably be the best way to go about doing it

Comment: @BradleyMackey thank you so much for your advice, you've been very helpful!